# Detecting abnormal shifts in Time Series data

Tags: r, time-series, structural-change

What is the best way to know if recent time series data is abnormally different from the historic data, consider this:

[image]

The data just beyond Nov 15 looks like it has shifted low - but what techniques can tell me if this shift is abnormal..?

I'm currently using Changepoint detection in R from the changepoint package - but this will find multiple changepoints if all of the data is considered. And if I use only the more recent data it will find the change, but how can I know if its abnormal wrt the overall population..?

Paul.

Comment: Yes, there was a visible shift around Nov 15.  However, the new range is no different than observed in late October.  What, then, do you mean by "abnormal"?  Do you mean that the *fact there was a shift* is unusual?  That the amount of the shift is unusual?  That the data immediately before or after the shift are unusual?  Something else?  And what would the "overall population" be?  Would it be as reflected in the raw data, regardless of time, or would it be the *probability model* for the data, taking into account historical shifts, trends, seasonality, and correlation etc.?

Comment: Do you mean that the fact there was a shift is unusual?   - yes I can see the shift, i'm trying to gage in the overall data set that you see is this 'anomalous' i can eyeball it and say, yeah it was once in that region before - but given the time that has passed since this...is this expected/abnormal..?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

You could start by defining what is normal and then assess the data from that perspective. E.g. build a model and see if some of the data happen to be outliers in the context of that model. E.g. look at $m$-day moving averages and see if a given day is far away from that. Subject-matter knowledge could be helpful in assessing whether a given deviation from the "normal" behaviour is "large" or "small".

Alternatively, you could do unsupervised clustering that would identify groups of similar data points. If time-adjacent data points belong to different clusters, a change might have happened between these time points. You would of course have to think hard how to measure distance between points for this to work well (e.g. you might or might not want to consider series of adjacent points rather than single points, this way including or excluding "history" of a given data point).